# Is it possible to set top_level for bdist_wheel?

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py, python-wheel

I have a project with a structure similar to this:

```
project_name
  |_ module_1
    |_ submodule1
    |_ file1.py
  |_ module_2
  |_ filea.py
  |_ fileb.py
  |_ setup.py
```

If I create a `bdist_wheel` from it, when installing I will get the files and module folder directly under `site-packages`.

I can add another level to the tree, like so:

```
project_name
  some_name
    |_ module_1
      |_ submodule1
      |_ file1.py
    |_ module_2
    |_ filea.py
    |_ fileb.py
    |_ setup.py
```

and then I get everything installed under `some_name` in `site-packages`.

Question is, can I achieve the same by somehow setting `top_level` or by other means that doesn't require adding another folder to the hierarchy (code is like in former in GIT)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like the following could work, but I am not sure (haven't tested it), it might also be required to exclude `setup.py` somehow, I would not recommend it anyway:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    packages=['some_name', 'some_name.module_1'],
    package_dir={'some_name': '../project_name'},
    # ...
)
```

**References**:

- https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html?highlight=package_dir#listing-whole-packages

Comment: Tested the above and it work. Thought I would need to override `build`, but `setup.py` was not included by `bdist_wheel`.