# github repo installed through pip has no modules

Tags: pip, module

I am trying to convert a [repo over to a pip package](https://github.com/WASasquatch/BLIP-Python) with a generic `setup.py` I got [from here](https://github.com/navdeep-G/setup.py). I don't exactly understand what I'm doing wrong, and my packages look just like how tutorials, and other projects look.

However upon successful installation, the project only has a info dir. There is no module directory. Upon inspecting the package, it shows it's installing to the base `dist-packages` dir, not a subdir.

My [**setup.py**](https://github.com/WASasquatch/BLIP-Python/blob/main/setup.py) has this to define the modules:

`packages=find_packages(include=[NAME, f'{NAME}.*']),`

Which works, but no modules are apparently found, or installed.

I've also tried

`py_modules=[NAME, f'{NAME}.configs', f'{NAME}.data', f'{NAME}.models', f'{NAME}.transform'],`

But this just exist with error code 1.

Comment: I recommend you follow this tutirial: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ -- Note that you will need to change the project's directory structure. Pay close attention to the directory structure in the tutorial. You will need to move all Python code to a new directory; `src/blip_comfy`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look. I'm just curious why other projects using similar packaging (or copied and name var just changed) works, and they don't have any src dir or anything.

Comment: Do you have examples you can link me to?

Comment: @sinoroc check out this project I forked that can install via PIP just fine: https://github.com/WASasquatch/img2texture

Original project is also in pipi, it uses similar architecture with just a folder named after module, and even tried using it's packaging code.

Comment: The big difference is that the `img2texture` project has all the actual Python code inside the `img2texture` directory, which then (once installed) translates into one single top-level importable package (`import img2texture`). On the other hand `BLIP-Comfy` seems to have importable modules directly in the root directory of the project, and that's not good practice, it makes it hard if not impossible to package correctly. So your package does not in fact "_look just like how tutorials, and other projects look_".

Comment: I think it assumes github structure, where the root IS a package, under the repos name. So seems more like a shortcoming of pip packaging when utilizing github. Seems like that should be default usage anyway, so you don't nuke your `dist-packages` folder if names being installed to it would override other modules. Seems like a implementation problem.

Comment: What is this "GitHub structure" you are talking of? *pip* does not know or care about GitHub, it does not need to. That your project source code repository is hosted on GitHub, or even that it is a *git* repository is completely unrelated to your issue. Your project directory structure is your issue.

Comment: The Github support is [VCS Support](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/), VCS Support doesn't mention any of what you're talking about specifically as a must, and in fact shows project structures as I have done, and many projects ***actually use***.  So turns out, you just need to specify the folder. if it's not in a /src/ dir.

Comment: *pip*'s VCS support documentation chapter does not mention any of  this because it is not related at all. *pip* does not care about this. It is up to the build back-end, which in your case is *setuptools*. -- No your project structure is not a common one. -- You can try the following, but I really do not recommend it at all, and I have not tested since I wrote it so I do not know if it still works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62149832